# MS Teams Bot: test in web chat is unauthorized for Teams conversation bot from BotBuilder-Samples

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm having trouble setting this up https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot.

I used a bot channel registration and ngrok. I've replaced the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword(client secret) in the .env file. I also edited the app id in the manifest. But when I try to test the bot in web chat, it's giving me unauthorized with this error: JwtTokenExtractor.getIdentity:err! FetchError: request to https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

It works when I test it in the emulator locally. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it, and it works for me, All i did was create a bot channel registration, 
put the messaging endpoint https://xxxxxxa6ab9.ngrok.io/api/messages, and put the app reg secret and appid into the .env and ran the 2 things.

it sounds like you may have an antivirus/firewall blocking some of the communications between your ngrok or bot and outside. 
make sure you turn off third party firewalls and such, and just to confirm, you need 2 command windows to run this, one window to run ngrok and a separate window to run the npm start.

Comment: I am using 2 command windows for this. I wonder if it's really just a firewall between ngrok and bot because I also tried creating a web app bot hosted in Azure. I followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-bot-service-3.0

At first it says, internal server error when i tested in web chat then the tech support told me to change the appid and apppassword, it now says unauthorized even if i change it back to the previous values.

Comment: i just tested your "web app bot" page, created a web app bot with a bunch of random values. press create. there's not much there that can go wrong there, it just creates a web app bot and an app service for the bot and configures it... then click go to resource, click test in web chat, and type something and it works right away. echo: etc Hello and welcome! is what it responded. if even creating a basic c# bot with a few clicks is failing for you, then there are other issues at hand, do you have a normal azure tenant and azure ad? are you global admin of your azure tenant?

Comment: Exactly. That is why I'm wondering if maybe something is wrong with my Azure account instead. How do I know if I have a normal azure tenant and azure ad? I am not an admin.

Comment: that may be your issue, you may not have permissions to properly create app registrations in the azure ad tenant. which would make sense as to why you are getting unauthorized.

Comment: I already have an app registered by the admin and they made me an owner of this app so that I can manage it myself. What additional permission/s do I need for this?

Comment: thats good, please make sure they created it with Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Xbox, Outlook.com).  as per here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-bot-framework-faq?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#app-registration   if it was created without that option, the bot will fail.

Comment: You can check it by going to your app registration, and clicking authentication, the section under supported account types, will tell you what they set when they created it.

Comment: Hi, the supported account type for the app registration is Multitenant (Accounts in any organizational directory)

Comment: so as per the documentation it needs to be multitenant + microosft accounts.. that could be the reason its failing.

Comment: Can you please send a link to that documentation? Is this only applicable for Bot Channel Registration? Or also for Web App Bot?

Comment: sure, here the little blue blurb: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#manual-app-registration

Comment: That's weird. In the docs, it says "one of the 2 multi-tenant types that is: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD - Multitenant) or Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Xbox, Outlook.com)" and my app registration is Multitenant so it should have worked. Anyway , I tried building a bot using https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new and it works successfully now. Thank you!